# Templates problems in django

Tags: python, django-templates

I wrote an app in django. And I want to write a index.html for it. But I can't make it run. I tried and inspect the settings and code but, it doesn't work either. I will paste the code. Hope someone can find the trick.

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**I wrote a app named blog. I put the index.html in the ,*blog/templates/blog/***

```
views.py

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published=True)
    return render(request,'blog/index.html',{'posts':posts})



urls.py:

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

I can't find any problems but it just does not work. It seems the template is not found but the config path is right. Or I missed something that I unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

Add 'blog' to the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple in `settings.py`

Also, below are the settings that work for me. Hope these will do the trick for you as well.

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_DIR_NAME = os.path.split(PROJECT_BASE_PATH)[1]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_BASE_PATH, 'templates').replace('\\', '/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )
```

Comment: The only difference between our settings is the TEMPLATE_LOADERS and I add it but no changes  happened still. And I of course added <strong>"blog" into  INSTALLED_APPS</strong>. Everything is fine. But the index.htmi seems not loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I think I go the trick. It is problem of inheritance  of the template. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just curious Animesh, why the `replace('\\', '/')`? Can't you just use forward slashes in Django and have it work regardless of *nix / Windows?